# Surname is different on passport and visa

Tags: usa

My kid's H4 visa is stamped with a surname which is not there on the passport.

So on the passport the given name is there: Abhinav Singh and the surname is blank.

On the visa, the given name is Abhinav and the surname is Singh.

Now, I want to know whether this would be a problem  while travelling to US.

Note: the visa was attached to one of the page of his passport by the embassy

Comment: Was his visa attached to one of the pages of his passport by an embassy?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, this will be a problem. But there is a way to resolve it.

Yes: 
Because the surnames on both documents are not the same, the immigration/customs officer may not think that this is the same person or may think that the visa is fake. This has happened to my family member before because of the maiden name vs. non-maiden name. She had 2 official documents within the passport but with 2 different surnames (similar to your situation).

The way she resolved it was by getting a notarized letter from the embassy explicitly stating that the person with 2 different names are in fact the same person. She generally only presented the letter whenever the immigration/customs officer asked. So sometimes, the officer didn't notice. But if they did, she always had the document as a backup.

Comment: The likelihood that such a letter will be necessary would probably be less in this case, since the names aren't different; they're just distributed differently.  Still, it might be helpful to have such a letter, and it can't hurt.